# How to fix this loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, factorial

I cannot initialize i and change the value of x
I'm trying to find the factorial form inverse order

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int x, i;
    cin >> x;
    float fact = x*i;
    do { 
        fact = fact*i;
        i = x -1;
        --x;
    } while( x >= 0 );
    cout << fact << endl; 
}
```

I expect the output of 5! = 120

Comment: why not use `(x-1)` till `x` becomes `1`? You won;t need `i` anyways.

Comment: "i cannot initialize i" why not? Whats wrong with `int i=1;` ?

Comment: Sure you can initialize `i`: `int x, i = 1;`.

Comment: @fredrik the algorithm is fine, the problem is the use of unitialized variables

Comment: I didn't write that it was a fault in the algorithm... just that he would find the problem if he did...

Comment: @fredrik how will you notice unitiailzed variables with pen and paper?

Comment: the solution is clear, but it is not clear why or what you think is the problem, hence it is hard to answer. Just as a suggestion, maybe post the code where you do initialize `i` but run into some other problem. Currently it is not clear what you mean with "... without change the value of x"

Comment: @fredrik i know that i didn't intialize i because if i did it will be fixed and will not change inside the loop

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 oops i mean it "..and change the value of x.."

Comment: @OmarElsehity "it will be fixed and will not change inside the loop" Why? Of course it will, it's not like it's immutable

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 you wouldn't? How would you manage the multiplication if you don't have the value?

Comment: @fredrik I am slightly confused by your insisting on a comment you deleted right after my reply. I find this pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize `i` and your algorithm is slightly flawed. Comment in the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() // void isn't valid
{
    int i = 1; // initialize
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    float fact = (x * i);
    do {
        fact = fact * i;
        i = x - 1;
        --x;
    } while(x > 0); // if x==0 is accepted it means i==0 next round and "fact = fact * 0"
    std::cout << fact << "\n";
}
```

You could write a function like this instead:

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits

float fact(int x) {
    float fact = 1.f;

    if(x < 0) { // let's not deal with negative factorials
        fact = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    } else {
        for(; x > 0; --x) {
            fact *= static_cast<float>(x);
        }
    }

    return fact;
}
```

And check that it looks ok:

```
int main() {
    for(int i = -1; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << "\t" << fact(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-1      nan
0       1
1       1
2       2
3       6
4       24
5       120
6       720
7       5040
8       40320
9       362880
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the variable `i` as we don't need it. Also correct the condition in `while` loop since we don't want `fact*0`

```
int main() {

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    float fact = 1;
    do {
        fact = fact * x;
        x--;
    } while (x > 0);
    std::cout << fact << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Warning: No validation for 0 or negative is done here.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x,i=1;
    cin>>x;
    float fact = x*i;
    do{ 
        fact=fact*i;
        i=x-1;
        --x;
    }while (x>0);
    if (x == 0)
       fact = 1;
    cout<<fact<<endl; 
}
```

Some minor changes from your code. this might helps:)

Comment: You should check whether `x` is 0 *before* the loop, and avoid looping if that's the case, otherwise you'll modify `x` in the first and only iteration, bringing it to -1 and getting a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version: (no check for overrun)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial (int x){  // a recursive function

    int res = 0;

    if (x ==1) return 1;
    else
        return x * factorial (x -1);   // call the function, with the immediate previous number
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    int fact = -1;
    cin>>x;

    fact = factorial(x);
    cout<<fact<<endl; 
}
```

You won't need an extra variable here.

Comment: @OmarElsehity please stop changing the accepted answer. You can only accept one. Settle on one and leave it there.